# CSV uploaded to FTP is broken

Tags: php, csv, ftp

I am generating CSV file locally and then upload to ftp using fwrite().

However I get the file destroyed after uploading to FTP.

When I compare the local copy and the ftp copy I see that my local file is fine and ftp copy has no line breaks.

What can it be related to? Would fputcsv() solve the problem?

Thank you

Comment: To answer your first question, we need more info in order to tell what the problem might be. For the second one, why not try it and figure it out ;)

Comment: Is it "broken" in that sense, that you suddenly cant read the file with `fgetcsv)`??

Comment: If your problem is that the FTP'ed version doesn't have line enders, show the code you are using and we can try to find out why.